# How to make use of a shared session for multiple database operation in slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm using slick, and have a question about slick session. I'll give an example first,
An Order class contains line items, Order can either fetch line items or remove one of the line item, and Order also can price it self. Below is the pseudocode:

class Order{

```
  def getLineItems= database withSesison{
      //get Line Items from db repository   
  }

  def removeLineItem(itemId: String) = database withTransaction{
      implicit ss: Session =>
      //Remove item from db
      //Price the order
  }

  def priceOrder() = database withTransaction{
      implicit ss: Session =>
      //getLineItems
      //recalculate order price by each line item
  }
}
```

So when I try to remove a line item, it will create a new Session and transaction, and then it will invoke priceOrder, which will also create a new Session and transaction, priceOrder will invoke getLineItems, which create another new session.

From slick document, I know each session is opening a jdbc connection, so in one method invocation it will create 3 database connection, it's a waste of connection resource. Is there a way to use only one connection to finish this operation?

I know slick has a threadLocalSession which bound the session to thread local, but from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/Sg42HDEK34Q I see we should avoid to use threadLocalSession.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new session/transaction for each method, you can use currying to pass an implicit session.

```
def create(user: User)(implicit session: Session) = {
  val id = Users.returning(Users.map(_.id)).insert(user)
  user.copy(id = Some(id))
}
```

Then, in a controller or some place, when you want to call the methods, you setup a session/transaction and it will be used for all database work within that block.

```
// Create the user.
DB.withTransaction { implicit session: Session =>
  Users.create(user)
}
```

Implicit sessions are how some of the Slick examples are setup. https://github.com/slick/slick-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/examples/lifted/MultiDBCakeExample.scala

Comment: Thanks Rob, you are right. But sometimes I don't want to surround the session outside, because I may invoke the method like getLineItems  in UI layer or other place, so I need the session right there in the entity object which will be convenient for ues.